# finding the mean of numbers in a file using functions and arrays in c

Tags: arrays, c, function

Trying to write a program that can find the mean of numbers from data files. I need to use one function to scan the numbers from the file into an array, then another function to find the mean of those numbers. Right now, I'm just trying to figure out getting the mean of one of the files. The code I currently have prints either -nan(ind) or a huge number. I think the issue in in my function to scan the numbers into an array, but I can't find the problem. I don't have the files I'll be scanning yet, I just know there will be (at least) 500 numbers in them.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void read_file(FILE* inp, double z[], int length);
double calc_mean(int length, double z[]);

int main(void) {
    FILE* data1;
    FILE* data2;
    int d1[500], d2[500];
    double mean, x;

    data1 = fopen("data1.txt", "r");
    data2 = fopen("data2.txt", "r");

    read_file(data1, d1, 500.0);
    x = calc_mean(500.0, d1);
    printf("%lf", x);


    fclose(data1);
    fclose(data2);
    return(0);
}


void read_file(FILE* inp, double z[], int length) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        fscanf(inp, "%d", &z[i]);
    }
}

double calc_mean(int length, double z[]) {
    double sum = 0.0, mean;
    int i;

    for (i = 1.0; i <= length; i++) {
        sum = sum + z[i];
    }
    mean = sum / length;
    return(mean);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `.0` in all your integer constants?

Comment: `i <= length` should be `i < length`

Comment: And that loop should start from `i = 0` not `i = 1`. So you're skipping the first element, and accessing an element after the end of the array.

Comment: Your functions are declared to take array of `double`, but `d1` is an array of `int`.

Comment: Also, shouldn't the fscanf format be "%lf" ?

Comment: What does the file actually contain, integers or floats?